# Text + Text when a value is NULL (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Server. I have a query

```
select FirstName, + ", " + LastName as FullName
```

If LastName = NULL and FirstName = "Fred"

Then FullName would be NULL. Is there a way to just have the FirstName instead?

Here is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbLWL.png

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with

```
Select Case 
    When LastName Is Null 
    Then FirstName 
    Else Concat(FirstName, ", ", LastName) 
End As FullName
```

Answer (score 2):

Since SQL Server 2017, you can use [`concat_ws()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select concat_ws(', ', firstname, lastname)
```

In earlier versions, you can use:

```
select stuff( concat(', ' + firstname,
                     ', ' + lastname
                    ), 1, 2, ''
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `concat` function, if you are having very old sql server version, you can use ISNULL to fill up empty string in place of null value.

```sql
select 
CASE WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL 
     THEN ISNULL(FirstName,'') + ", " + LastName
     ELSE ISNULL(FirstName,'') END as FullName
```